# Android setPressed behavior

Tags: android, button, simulate, pressed

The following code is an attempt to simulate a key stroke:

```
button1.setPressed(true);
try {
Thread.sleep(500);
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
} 
button1.setPressed(false);
```

The above does nothing at all to the button, but

```
button1.setPressed(true);
```

by itself sets the button to it's pressed state.
Why does the first snippet have no effect on the button?

Comment: If you are also trying to execute the Button's OnClickListener then remember to call button1.performClick(). (but maybe you just removed that part here to make the code cleaner/clearer) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late reply, but my guess would be because you are blocking the UI-thread, so it will not update the UI until you've already disabled the pressed state again.

Instead you could try something like;

```
class MyClass extends Activity ... {
  private final Handler _handler = new Handler();
  ...
  void somefunc() {
    button1.setPressed(true);
    _handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        button1.setPressed(false);
      }
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

Good luck!